# How to start and access under Windows 2 different Webserver under different URL using Docker?

Tags: docker, windows-10, vmware-workstation

I have installed Docker for Windows and could start a webserver(nginx).
I am using Docker Version: 18.06.1-ce-win73 (19507) and Windows Version: 10.0.16299 Enterprise.

For now i can access in the browser of the host OS (windows) under "http://localhost/" the webserver.

What i would like to do is following:

Start 2 webserver(webA[nginx] and webB[apache]) using docker and access them trough the host browser.
I would like to have e.g. "http://webA" to access webA and "http://webB" to access webB.

I tried to give the container different IPs and used host-file but it did not work. Like i read under: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers it is not possible to bind it is not possible to bind an IP to a container under windows.

Now i try to use docker in a VMWare where i start a linux but imho seems this approach a bit heavy.

How to achieve this?

Comment: you need to use a different port for the second nginx container

Comment: but the webServerS will communicate over the same ports so i need different urls, or do i mess something up?

Comment: you need to configure _one_ nginx for different web servers:
`server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  webA;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  webB;
    ...
}`

Comment: @malyy good idea but one uses apache2 other nginx ... i changed the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two different ports for 2 services.

You run your nginx container like

```
docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 80:80 some-content-nginx
```

And then run apache like

```
docker run -dit --name my-apache -p 8080:80 my-apache2
```

The result is you get a nginx on http://localhost:80 and apache on http://localhost:8080.

If you want to have http://webA.yourdomain.com, you will have to either config vhost on your host, or use a proxy like `traefik`.

Answer (score 1):

> Start 2 webserver(webA[nginx] and webB[apache]) using docker and access them trough the host browser. I would like to have e.g. "http://webA" to access webA and "http://webB" to access webB.

In order to have all sites working on one port there is apossibility to use one webservice as a proxy.
Here is an example for docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx_siteA: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_siteA
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
# all other stuff 
...

  apache_siteB:
    image: httpd:latest
    container_name: httpd_siteB
# all other stuff 
...
```

So, in this example 2 web services are configured and can reach each other from docker network (you can ping or/and curl apache from nginx and via versa). But from machine host - you can reach only nginx using 80 port.
P.S. `nginx_siteA` and `apache_siteB` are the service names, and it is possible to use them in config files as domain names (hostnames)

And configure nginx to work directly with siteA and proxy SiteB like:

```
server {
    server_name siteA;
    # all other stuff   
    ......
}
server {
    server_name siteB;
    location /{
      proxy_pass http://apache_siteB;
    }
# all other stuff 
....
}
```

Or, use apache container in the same way:
install `mod_proxy` and in Apache domain.conf file add to `VirtualHost` block directive: `ProxyPass / http://nginx_siteA/`